# how to reduce solr memory usage?

Tags: solr, jetty

I use solr in my application, there is just hundreds of documents. 
the memory usage is about 80M,  how to reduce it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

80M is not much, in fact it's pretty much the mininum, you won't go much lower than that.

Some factors that affect memory usage:

- Input document size
- Multi-threaded document updates
- Cache size
- Facet queries
- Sorting

References:

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Factors_affecting_memory_usage
- http://www.nabble.com/Debugging-Solr-memory-usage-heap-problems-td8832794.html
- http://osdir.com/ml/solr-user.lucene.apache.org/2009-02/msg00050.html
- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/200905.mbox/%3C552701.4457.qm@web50308.mail.re2.yahoo.com%3E