# Apache SOLR erratic RAM comsumption

Tags: apache, solr, django-haystack

I've set up SOLR indices on my computer, and everything works fine.

I'm not experienced with SOLR but after profiling the "start.jar" process for a while, I've noticed that the RAM consumption jumps around a lot, anywhere from 150MB to 400MBish. And this is just for 10K documents!

So as a response, I wrote a script that just waits for SOLR to go past my RAM consumption limit (on shared hosting), and when it does, it kills start.jar and restarts it.

Does this have any adverse effect? And if so, what better solutions are there, besides get more RAM or use cloud based SOLR (which also costs money)? Sorry if this sounds stupid but I just need a working solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Solr is memory hungry, no way around it. However see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546898/how-to-reduce-solr-memory-usage

Comment: Yes, thanks. But will my solution of just killing SOLR and restarting it when memory usage goes past the limits have any adverse affects, aside from the search functionality not being available for a short amount of time.

Comment: You're killing all Solr caches so performance will suffer greatly. That said, if you don't need high QPS it might be fine for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some Index stats:

How big is your index (no. of docs & size in MB/GB)?
How many fields indexed/stored?
How much memory is allocated to JVM?
Do you optimize/commit, very often/realtime?
What is the SOLR Query time you see in logs?

Best